# Rails overriding migration template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to override the Rails generators for new models and new migrations. The model override works, but the scaffold override is not working.

Here is the structure of my lib folder.

[image]

Comment: did you manage to get that working?

Comment: @phoet, no. I could override all the other templates, but no luck with the migration template, and just gave up.

Comment: i saw that in rails4 there were 2 different templates for migrations. the other one is `migration.rb`

Comment: Yes, I was trying to override create_table_migration.rb.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place your override in:

```
lib/templates/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb
```

This is likely a bug in Rails 4.x that can be fixed by
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13972

Comment: and this still persist on rails 5.x

Comment: If it helps anyone else, the original `create_table_migration.rb` can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb.tt).